# How to show a success / failure message on contact form submit

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to to show that a message was either sent or not in a contact form. At the moment on success or failure it is redirecting to a designated success or failure page. All I'm looking to do is instead of redirect, maybe show a div, or modal or popup but I'm not sure how to do that in PHP.

Form:

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7 contactboxform">
    <form action="contact_me.php" method="POST" id="contactform">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." class="input-text">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number..." class="input-text">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address..." class="input-text">
      <input type="checkbox" name="interested">
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="What would you like to say?" class="input-text text-area" rows="7"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" id="subbtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

PHP:

```
// send email
if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone) && !empty($message)) {
    $success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, "From: <$emailFrom>");
}
if ($success){
    header('Location: success.html');
}
else {
    header('Location: failed.html');
}
//redirect to success page
```

So I'm just not sure how to properly say in PHP that on success, show specific div / popup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need AJAX for that as PHP cannot perform client-side actions.

Comment: Is redirecting really an issue? You can redirect back to the same page and in the view read a `$status` variable to show a message. It would need to be stored in a `$_SESSION` to get at it on a redirect though and you will have to unset it in the end.

Comment: can you trigger an AJAX event through PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a `div` and then inserting into it a response from a AJAX request.

For example, add to your HTML code:

```
<div id="form_status"></div>
```

When the submit button is clicked, you perform the AJAX request:

```
<button type="submit" id="subbtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onClick="validateForm();">Submit</button>
```

And the `validateForm` function can be:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var status = $('div#form_status');
    var form = $('form#contactform');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-php-file.php?'+form.serialize()
    }).done(function(data){
        status.html(data);
    });
}
```

On `your-php-file.php`, you can access all the data from the form with `$_GET['input_name']`, with `input_name` being the `name` of the input on the form.

With this, anything that you print on the `your-php-file.php` will be printed into the `div#form_status`, without the need to refresh the page.